# Array of element in WSDL File

Tags: web-services, soap, soa, soapui

Hello I'm developping  some web services in java, so I have created a wsdl file to describe this services.

With my wsdl I create the web services (servcer side). but I can't create the client side because

I think the problem is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bil="http://tempuri.org/Services/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bil:ArrayOfElement soapenc:arrayType="?" soapenc:offset="?" id="?" href="?">
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <Element>
            <code>?</code>
            <codeElement>?</codeElement>
            <TypeService>?</TypeService>
         </Element>
      </bil:ArrayOfElement>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In fact, I don't know what we must put in this line:

```
<bil:ArrayOfElement soapenc:arrayType="?" soapenc:offset="?" id="?" href="?">
```

And for my tests I send this enveloppe and it works (but like you see it's another wsdl):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bil="http://tempuri.org/Services/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bil:ArrayOfElement>
                   <Element>
                <code>exmepleCode</code>
                <codeElement>exmempleCodeElement</codeElement>
                <TypeService>a_Service_Type</TypeService>
             </Element>
      </bil:ArrayOfElement>

      <!-- other elements-->

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the WSDL?

one important issue when working with web services, or xml schemas (xsd) in general, is that there's no simple one to one mapping between xsd and language specific types (java in this case).

one of the implication is when doing a 'round trip' mapping (java to xsd, and then xsd to java) you don't get always what you started with - especially when using non simple types such as arrays or other containers.

The solution in this case is to create a "correct" xsd schema, and derive the javadefinitions for  the client and the server from this schema - only a single xsd to java transformation is done, so no issues of rount trip mapping are encountered.
To create such a xsd, you should use the native methods of defining collections in xsd, which is basically adding `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` attributes to the basic element.

you can find more detailed reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints)

Note that you don't have to use hand crafted xsd - you can also use any xsd editor (most modern IDE's have one) to get the same results.

Comment: <bil:ArrayOfElement soapenc:arrayType="?" soapenc:offset="?" id="?" href="?">

Comment: What I suggest (as a general method) is to create a new xsd using an xsd editor (not generate the xsd from a java class) - and generate the java classes (both proxy and stub) from this xsd.

Comment: OK, that what I do actually, but I don't create a xsd but wsdl file. I create it manually in eclipse. and then I generate classes.